# Custom decorator is not taken into account outside of a component

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to develop a custom decorator into my angular app, to register classes into a list. It is located outside a component.

I have a base abstract class:

```
export abstract class Tool {
  abstract name: string;
  constructor(protected name: string, protected iconPath: string) {
  }

  abstract aMethod();
  // etc
}
```

The goal is to register every derived class into a list, to use them into a factory. So I wrote a class decorator to make it easier to use, and more flexible:

*tools.decorator.ts*

```
import { Tool } from './tool.abstract';

export const tools: {
  [key: string]: { new: (...args: any[]) => Tool }
} = {};


export function RegisterTool() : ClassDecorator {
  console.log('Register class');
  return function (cls: any) {
    console.log('name: ',cls.name)
    tools[cls.name] = {
      new: (...args: any[]) => new cls(...args),
    };

    return cls;
  };
}
```

Then I tried to use the decorator on an example class:

```
@RegisterTool()
class TestTool extends Tool {
  override toolName = 'test_tool';

  override aMethod() {
    // ....
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to import the tools list from *tool.decorator.ts* to a component, and log its content, I only see the void object as it was initialized.
Also, None of the log wrote in the decorator function are visible in the console.

In conclusion, my decorator doesn't seem to be executed, but I can't find why.

Is it possible, and if so then how ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what is wrong in you code, but the following example works:

```
abstract class Tool {
  abstract toolName: string;
  constructor(protected name: string, protected iconPath: string) {
  }

  public say(): void {
    console.log(this.toolName);
  }
}

const tools: {
  [key: string]: { new: (...args: any[]) => Tool }
} = {};


function RegisterTool() : ClassDecorator {
  console.log('Register class');
  return function (cls: any) {
    console.log('name: ',cls.name)
    tools[cls.name] = {
      new: (...args: any[]) => new cls(...args),
    };

    return cls;
  };
}

@RegisterTool()
class TestTool extends Tool {
  override toolName = 'test_tool';
}

console.log(tools);
const obj = tools['TestTool'].new();
obj.say();
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgKge28hA3gLABQCCokM8CEuyAcsALYCmAXAlQJYB2A5gG5S5WNl5UArvGxQAFAAco2CK3isAJgl4sOXaH34AaBEpVrVW7mN4AFYBAAWnHgICUhEQgC%20pLwskQZGsuYABPOTdOADdsbi1iMnIkcTA8VgA6ZGx%20OSduMAy6PCY2N2Ek3xIq0htIWnowTkTyAG0Aa1YwlwMBAF1m7VYAd045DIngKH4mil4w1r6PAF4APix6H1JvBGXCbwq-EgAzSV54bnEEACVWfgLVKBw8SIROAGFUdAARNVkHWSeJJ1dJZHJyADkt3ukFYUCQXzAEPKXigrAgkigvAQp3OEEu2LkKFmwHmHhayRByEy2VyEJ0bE4EKMxIyDNYbi85GKyDArVZ7L6uyByWSvBGYwmGSmM04pIWS1263FwwRYHGk2mYDcRi5PkOSXIaIxWLVFXIB22RwAAtCHnDnshIrVEVhWJBHQhWAAPVS8DQYT0U7DROFQeKsBolXTCiGqSAAfR5EIqNRIVJp4J52oqdUQ2BAACthdnWhDMO6II6IX02SNIhUC4WMmBwg2gA)

Comment: How have you tested it ? It doesn't work for me

Comment: I've added link to playground, click run button.

Comment: The problem is that your example is not running in an angular app. Thanks for you help anyway !

Comment: It does work in angular, however class names are mangled in prod mode, you can not use `cls.name` as a key, you could pass name as an argument to the decorator.